# How can I get the body of an action as string

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1

I have two actions. The first serves single assets and the second should serve all the single assets combined into one asset. So my idea was to call the first action which serves the single assets from the second action which serves the combined asset. Some of you will say this is a bad idea, because I could load the assets directly from file system and combine them. But this isn't possible, because the first action is chained with other actions to do some additional operations(Fingerprinting, ...) on a asset.

**So here are my actions:**

The first serves a single asset. In this implementation it calls only the next action in the chain.

```
abstract override def at(path: String, file: String): Action[AnyContent] = {
  super.at(path, file)
}
```

The second accepts a list of files as JSON. Then it iterates over the list and calls the first action with a single file.

```
def consolidate = Action(parse.json) { request =>
  val files = request.body.as[List[String]]
  for (file <- files) {
    val action = at(path, new URL(file).getPath.substring(1))
    val result = action.apply(request)
  }
  Ok()
}
```

Now my problem is, how can I get the asset as string? The variable result contains a `Iteratee[Array[Byte], Result]`. How can I extract the asset data from it?

The *play.api.test.Helper* object contains a *contentAsString* and a *contentAsBytes* method. But this doesn't help me further!

Answer (score 0):

The `Iteratee` represents the consumer side of the action. There is no documentation for the method returning the `Iteratee` but I'm guessing it will be used to consume the input stream of data from the client during a request. So, in short, it won't help you here.

You could take the code from the first action, the one you need to invoke in `consolidate` and factor it out into some method, and use that method in both actions. Is that feasible for you ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think that you are wrong with the statement about the _Iteratee_. I think the _Iteratee_ contains the source of the asset. If none of the chained AssetProviders returns an asset, it falls back to the default play framework [_Asset_ controller](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/controllers/Assets.scala#L126). And this controller creates an enumerator from the assets which feeds the _Iteratee_ returned by the action. So in this implementation it's the consumer side of the asset.